# Verificar se campo numérico de formulário html possui no máximo 6 números com PHP

Tags: php, html

Preciso testar se campo está preenchido e se é composto de até 6 números utilizando a linguagem PHP

Comment: Poderia descrever melhor onde está com dificuldade?

Comment: Claro, 
tenho 2 campos em um form e um deles é numero_de_registro,

Comment: esse número pode ter no máximo 6 caracteres

Comment: preciso usar PHP para validar, verificar, se o campo possui esses 6 números ou não
se sim, ele envia os dados, senão, retorna ao índice

Comment: Precisa mesmo validar um formulário HTML em PHP? O ideal seria em javascript, porque a validação pode ser feita durante o preenchimento, sendo que em PHP a validação só seria feita depois do submit, algo não muito otimizado para o usuário.

Comment: é para uma tarefa, por isso a necessidade em PHP, senão já teria o feito em JS

Comment: @RogérioDec deve-se fazer sempre a verificação do lado servidor, mais importante do que fazer do lado cliente. Idealmente é nos dois, mas em javascript é só mais user friendly, porque não dá segurança nenhuma

Answer (score 7):

Você pode verificar se um campo está preenchido de diversas maneiras:

```
if($campo != NULL )
if(!$campo)
if(!$campo == "")
if(isset($campo))
if(!empty($campo))
if(strlen($campo) > 0) 
if(!strlen($campo)) // porque esta função retorna zero caso o $campo esteja vazio
```

O `!`serve para negar uma operação, "avalia" o inverso do que consta a seguir.

Para verificar se o `$campo` contém no máximo 6 números pode usar `strlen` como anteriormente:

```
if(strlen($campo)<=6 && strlen($campo))
```

Agora deverá usar o que se enquadra melhor as suas necessidades.

> **Referências:**
>      [NULL](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php)
>      [isset](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)
>      [empty](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)
>      [strlen](http://strlen)

Comment: Se existe algo de errado com a minha resposta para além do -1 por favor comente, ninguém é perfeito, estamos todos aqui para aprender e partilhar conhecimento.

Comment: pois é, eu comentei aqui uma solução, e tem gnt que sinaliza com negativamente, vai entender.

Answer (score 3):

Além das outras respostas, que estão corretas. Eu acredito que você quer avaliar se o campo está preenchido de até **6 NÚMEROS**. Criei duas opções:

***Opção 1***

Você pode usar o **[is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.is-numeric.php)**:

Ele retornará verdadeiro se a string for uma string numérica, e junto com o `strlen` das outras respostas você conseguirá o que pretende:

```
$numeros = trim($_POST['numero_de_registro']);

if(is_numeric($numeros) && $numeros != "" && strlen($numeros) <= 6){
    echo "Está tudo certo aqui -> ".$numeros;
}
```

Exemplos de retorno do `is_numeric`:

```
"123a" -> false
"123"  -> true
" 123" -> true
"1a2"  -> false
```

***Opção 2***

Usando o **[preg_match](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php)**

O `preg_match` vai retornar 1 se a avaliação for correta. Ou seja, se houver 6 dígitos nesta string:

```
$numeros = trim($_POST['numero_de_registro']);
if(preg_match("/\d{1,6}/", $numeros)){
    echo "Está tudo certo aqui -> ".$numeros;
}
```

Entendendo as siglas:

```
\d    -> dígitos [0-9]
{1,6} -> quantidade dígitos que devem existir nessa avaliação, no mínimo 1 e no máximo 6
```

Se você não quiser o `0`, você pode alterar para isso:

```
preg_match("/[1-9]{1,6}/", $numeros);
```

Answer (score 2):

Usando php você usa a função `strlen()`, que conta o numero de caracteres da string:

```
$str=strlen($_POST['sua_variável']);
if($str==6){echo 'ok';}
```